# Logparser 2.2 and regex/sql

Tags: python, sql, regex, logparser

Does logparser not support the use of regex? im trying to match a string pattern, everytime I try to use it i get an error of invalid syntax. Also when i replace regexp with LIKE i believe it's just doing a string comparison with the literal regex rather than the pattern if that makes sense

```
    SELECT column FROM SOMEPATH
    WHERE column REGEXP '34 [0-9A-fa-f]{2} 55'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Work was started to support regex'es in 2.3, but that version never saw the light.